# MySQL alter All Columns In table

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables.There are columns in each table which have identical names.
Each table has for instance, "id" column.

These make for terrible arrays in PHP.

The solution to my trouble is to prepend column names with the name of the table.

Is there a MySQL statement which would add "name" to the start of every column in name the table? 
So that the `id` field in `people` table would become `peopleid`, for instance.

Comment: Had not heard of this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a select, you can give the column an alias.

```
SELECT id AS 'PeopleID' FROM People
```

Comment: This solution forces the programmer to indicate every single column name he would like to select. I would have almost 100 !   SELECT * is part of the protocol for this task.  Thanks though.